# IPageLayout in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have an eclipse 3.x RCP.

What is the proper way of obtaining the `IPageLayout` reference that gets passed to `createInitialLayout`?

I want to be able to add and find placeholders programmatically after the layout has been created.

I know that `createInitialLayout` gets called only once. After the RCP is closed, the workbench settings gets loaded from the preferences as well as the layout that was saved before closing.

Answer (score 0):

The `IPageLayout` only exists for the call to the perspective factory `createInitialLayout` method. It is not available anywhere else.

Plugins can use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to define additions to the perspective.

In Eclipse 4 using 3.x compatability mode all the above modify the application model `MPerspective` object using things like `MPlaceholder`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you though provide any example using `MPlaceholder` or `MPerspective`? I have tried injecting both `EPartService` and `EModelService` to see if I can use them but kept getting `InjectionException`.

Comment: I don't have any examples of using this in Eclipse 3.x code.

Comment: I suggest you look at the source code of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.ModeledPageLayout` which is the implementation of IPageLayout